# Python Database update error

Tags: python, mysql, database

Usually  i use Django orm for making database related query in python but now i am using the python itself

I am trying to update a row of my mysql database

```
query ='UPDATE callerdetail SET upload="{0}" WHERE agent="{1}" AND custid="{2}"AND screenname="{3}" AND status="1"'.format(get.uploaded,get.agent,get.custid,get.screenname)
```

But i am getting the error

```
query ='UPDATE callerdetail SET upload="{0}" WHERE agent="{1}" AND custid="{2}"AND screenname="{3}" AND status="1"'.format(get.uploaded,get.agent,get.custid,get.screenname)
```

AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'uploaded'

Please help me what is wrong with my query ?

Answer (score 0):

Get is probably mapping to a c object.  Try renaming your "get" object to something else.

Here is a list of [reserved words](http://pentangle.net/python/handbook/node52.html).  I don't see get in there, but it sound like it could be part of a c library that's being included.  If you're including something with **from x import ***, you could be importing it without knowing.

Answer (score 0):

In short - `get` probably isn't what you think it is.

However, before you go much further building SQL queries with string formatting, I strongly advise you not to! Search for "SQL injection" and you'll see why. Python DB API compliant libraries utilise "placeholders" which the library can use to insert the variables into a query for you providing any necessary escaping/quoting.

So instead of:

```
query ='UPDATE callerdetail SET upload="{0}" WHERE agent="{1}" AND custid="{2}"AND screenname="{3}" AND status="1"'.format(get.uploaded,get.agent,get.custid,get.screenname)
```

An example using SQLite3 (using `?` as a placeholder - others use `%s` or `:1` or %(name)s - or any/all of the above - but that'll be detailed in the docs of your library):

```
query = "update callerdetail set upload=? where agent=? and custid=? and screename=? and status=?"
```

Then when it comes to execute the query, you provide the values to be substituted as a separate argument:

```
cursor.execute(query, (get.uploaded, get.agent, get.custid, get.screenname))
```

If you really wanted, you could have a convenience function, and reduce this to:

```
from operator import attrgetter
get_fields = attrgetter('uploaded', 'agent', 'custid', 'screenname')
cursor.execute(query, get_fields(get))
```

Comment: The most common MySQL database adapter for Python uses `%s` style sql parameters (yes, echoing the python string formatting syntax).